# Wordpress Image Gallery remove from content

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with Wordpress post gallery:

I have create an php code that gets all post gallery images and show it on a jquery slide. When I add a post to my blog, I set "Create a Gallery" and after I click on "Insert into post". All things are good... my code gets all gallery images and show in a beutiful slide. But THE PROBLEM IS: how to delete gallery from post (because it appears where I put my slide and in post content)?

Please check this image for more explanation:

[image]

Thanks soooo much in advance!

Comment: Please help me... anyone?

Comment: i can not findout with your url:http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/03/colin/#.UeU1gqwR4ps

Comment: sorry, but this is not my url

Comment: oh, sorry, this appear over my slide, but it is not my URL

Comment: it is an external link...

Comment: `I have create an php code that gets all post gallery images and show it on a jquery slide.` - Show the code then.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, this will resolve your problem with loop file (functions.php).

You could only unregister gallery short code and register again as do nothing ;).

```
remove_shortcode('gallery');
add_shortcode('gallery', 'gallery_shortcode_lo');

function gallery_shortcode_lo($attr) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just filter content by class in functions.php, remove nodes and return new content. You can remove all galleries from post, and after that use own custom gallery style

```
    function remove_gallery($content) {
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        // turn off html5 errors
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        // load html with utf8
        $doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>'.$content);
        libxml_clear_errors();
        $finder = new DomXPath($doc);
        // find by class (you can also find by id one element without use DomXPath
        $nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' wp-block-gallery ')]");

        // remove them all
        foreach($nodes as $node){
          $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
        }
        
        // get only body, and clear what we need to 
        $body = $doc->documentElement->lastChild;
        $content = $doc->saveHTML($body);
        //remove body tag
        $content = str_replace("<body>", "", $content);
        $content = str_replace("</body>", "", $content);
        // clear HTML comments
        $content = preg_replace('/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/', '', $content);
        // clear return characters
        $content = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $content);

    return $content; 
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_gallery', 6);
```

Answer (score -1):

Open your post in edit mode.

Now click on visual layout.

Select the gallery, it will display two icon on the left top corner, click on second icon to remove gallery from the post.

Click on update button to save your changes.

Comment: Are you using any cache plugin ??